# How do I search multiple ranges?

Tags: python-3.x

Disclaimer: I'm 16 and have just started my A levels, Computing is one of my subjects.

So, I had a challenge, to make a tax rate calculator. I'm having issues trying to get the salaries to receive the correct tax discount:

```
personal_allowance = 11500    
basic_rate = range(11501,45001)    
higher_rate = range(45002,150001)
additional_rate = range(150002,(1 ** 15))

br_tax = float(0.2)
hr_tax = float(0.4)
ad_tax = float(0.45)
```

The trouble is when you differentiate the numbers:

```
#if not income_amount in basic_rate:
    print("You pay 20% tax. You will pay:\n£"+str("%.2f" % round((income_amount * br_tax),2)))
    income_amount = 0
    time.sleep(0.6)
    print("-------------")
    time.sleep(2)
    Start()
```

How do I get that commented line to sort itself out, I have ones for the higher salaries too but all default to this block rather than the others for the other ranges. Obviously `<` and `>` do not work and `not` `in` `is` combinations don't seem to help either.

As a side note, does that double asterisk work as an exponent since my code won't properly show me?

```
additional_rate = range(150002,(1 ** 15))
```

Comment: with a few small adjustments (mainly move `income_amount = 0` definition before the line it's printed in, and uncomment the `if` clause) code seems to work for me. I input, e.g. `60000`, and get `12000.0` back as the taxed rate. Is that not what is supposed to happen? Can you provide more explanation on what doesn't work? Sample inputs with expected outputs and incorrect outputs?

Comment: The `**` operators does do exponentiation, but you seem to be giving it the wrong arguments. `1**15` is `1` (since 1 raised to *any* power is 1). I'm guessing you wanted `10**15`. You may have it confused with exponential notation for floats, where `1e15` is the equivalent of `1.0 * 10**15`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could understand, you need to give different tax rates based on different income slabs?

The range function in python creates a sequence, for example, 
`range (1,5)` is the sequence `1,2,3,4.` Which, I feel is unnecessary here.

Your program will be easier if you used `if else` instead.

```
income = 20000 # income of the person

# Rates
br_tax = float(0.2)
hr_tax = float(0.4)
ad_tax = float(0.45)
tax_to_deduct = 0

# Calculate the tax on the amount first

if income>=11501 and income <= 45001:
    tax_to_deduct = br_tax*income

# Then subtract this from your original income.
print ('Tax:',tax_to_deduct)
print ('Income after tax:',income-tax_to_deduct)
```

Do the same for all the brackets, using `if else` will make your code much more intuitive. I might have misunderstood your question, let me know if that's the case.

Yes, the double asterisk works as exponent

Comment: Python's chained comparisons let you improve the code a bit more than what you have. Try `11501 <= income < 45001`, or even better `11500 < income <= 45000`.

Comment: @sarthank_khannaThat's brilliant, thank you! I did think to do it like that, however, I thought there might have been a quicker way to do it. This works exactly how I'd like. Thank you!